# Table in HTML Response not found for parsing

Tags: html, vba, http, parsing, post

I am sending a POST request and I confirmed that the expected data is there.

When trying to parse a table from that response text (HTML) VBA can't find any table.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetExchangeRates()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmlDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim URL As String

    URL = "http://www.medmouic.org/Advanced/TrouverAdv"

    XMLPage.Open "POST", URL, False
    XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3"
    XMLPage.send "imonumber=&val=0&Name=&selectFlag=333&selectType=&grossfrom=&grossTo=&yearFrom=&yearTo=&selectClass=&Countries=Selects+items&InspectResult=All&TypesDeficiencies=0&SortBy=Imo&fro=01.08.2019&to=31.08.2019"

    SaveHTMFile XMLPage.responseText
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    ProcessHTMLPage htmlDoc

End Sub

Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
        Debug.Print HTMLTable.className
    Next HTMLTable

End Sub
```

The "SaveHTMFile XMLPage.responseText" creates a TXT file where I find the table. I was expecting the "Debug.Print HTMLTable.className" to show "data-table" which is the class of the table, but instead I have nothing as a result.

```
<form method="post" action="/Advanced/TrouverAdv" id='myform'>

<table class="data-table" id="anyTable" >
    <!--- Sortby IMONUMBER---->
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#428bca">
                <th>IMO Number</th>
                <th>Ship Name</th>
                <th>Flag state</th>
                <th>Date of  inspection</th>
                <th>Place of inspection</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    9301433
                </td>
```

Comment: Have you checked that there is actual data inside `XMLPage.responseText`?

Comment: Yes, it returns an HTML document and my table is inside it. @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Could it be that the table is in a nested HTMLDoc?

Comment: That is very well possible. It shows as follows: 
<div id="content" style=" background:#eeeeee;">
<form method="post" action="/Advanced/TrouverAdv" id='myform'>
<table class="data-table" id="anyTable" >. Any sugestions to get around that? @Mrblackey